# Info on setting up a MariaDB 10.1.x Master-Master Cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to setup a new MariaDB 10.1.x cluster for a migrating a new application from mysql. I can't seem to find any info based on the new MariaDB 10.1.x, can somebody help me with this problem?? Has somebody done this??

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable the MariaDB 10.1.x repository. Depending on your Linux distribution and version, its content may differ. Here it is a [MariaDB repository generator](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=hs-esslingen).

On CentOS 6 x64 the **/etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo** has the following content:

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Next step is the installation itself. Check this link for details: http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/installmariadb.html

Or.. if you are on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora just run :

```
yum install MariaDB-Galera-server MariaDB-client galera
```

If MySQL was already installed on that machine, it will be replaced with latest MariaDB 10.1.x. You will not lose your databases, so don't worry.
Repeat the process for all the nodes.

The last and longest step is to read the [Galera Cluster Documentation](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/). Take your time to study it deeply. The better you understand what DB clustering is about, the less headaches you will have later.
Happy clustering! :-)

Comment: And do the "cluster" thing, _not_ Master-Master.  Galera Cluster is better and easier.